# Avoiding overfitting with random forest

Tags: random-forest, training-data

I am training a random forest model for the first time and I find this situation.

1. My accuracy on the training set, with the default parameters (as in 
   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html ) is very high, 0.95 or more , which looks a lot like overfitting. On the test set, accuracy goes to 0.66. My goal would be to make the model less overfitting, hoping to improve performance on the test set.
2. I tried to perform 5-fold cross validation, using random grid search like here ( https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-the-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-28d2aa77dd74 ) with the following grid:

```py
n_estimators = [16,32,64,128]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
bootstrap = [True, False]
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}
```

The best model had an accuracy of 0.7 across the folds.

3. I used the best selected parameters in step 2 on the training set and test set, but again accuracy on training set was 0.95 and test set 0.66.

Any suggestion ? What do you think is going on here ? How can I reach the result to avoid overfitting ( and maybe improve model performance ) ?

Comment: Why do you believe that you're overfitting? It's okay for the accuracy on the training set to be greater than on the test set.

Comment: Yes but the difference in accuracy is huge...

Comment: Sorry but why the downvote ? Please write suggestions to improve the question before downvoting

Answer (score 1):

Over here someone had the same question and received some helpful answers:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/random-forest-how-to-handle-overfitting

Your approach to use 5-fold crossvalidation is already very good and can perhaps be improved by utilizing 10-fold crossvalidation instead.

Another question you can ask yourself is about the quality of your data set. Are your classes balanced? If they aren't you could try to handle a class imbalance issue, because with imbalance comes usually a bias towards the majority class.

It is also possible that the dataset is perhaps not big enough and increasing it could boost your performance as well.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Following the link that you put I also found this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/what-measure-of-training-error-to-report-for-random-forests?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Adding this late comment in case it helps others.

In addition to the parameters mentioned above (n_estimators, max_features, max_depth, and min_samples_leaf) consider setting 'min_impurity_decrease'.

You can use 'gini' or 'entropy' for the Criterion, however, I recommend sticking with 'gini', the default. In the majority of cases, they produce the same result but 'entropy' is more computational expensive to compute.

Max depth works well and is an intuitive way to stop a tree from growing, however, just because a node is less than the max depth doesn't always mean it should split. If the information gained from splitting only addresses a single/few misclassification(s) then splitting that node may be supporting overfitting. You may or may not find this parameter useful, depending on the size of your dataset and/or your feature space size and complexity, but it is worth considering while tuning your parameters.

You do not describe how you split your dataset, so consider using a slightly smaller training set. Also make sure you do not have categorical variables in your feature space. If you do, use OneHotEncoding or pd.get_dummies to break those out.

I'm not sure how large your feature space is but you may want to use a smaller subset of your features (depending on how many noise variables you have). You also may want to look at a smaller max_depth. Your depth test all the way up to 110, that's very large. Again, I do not know your feature space but look to the lower end of your range to start and expand from there. i.e. try: [5, 7, 9] if 9 is optimal then adjust to say [9, 11, 13] etc. Although even a depth of 9 can cause overfitting (depending on the data) so be careful not to grow this too much. Possible pair with the gini index.